# How to add a click event handler to a google maps api marker object using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My HTML is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>MapTest</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mapContainer"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB1KzIyYJuVoPB84Rum7kH5uUETV-WIgSA"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/maps.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS is:

```
#mapContainer {
    width : 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

My jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var lat = 22.688138;
    var lng = 88.343926;

    function initMap()
    {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var mapOpts = {
            center : latlng,
            zoom : 20,
            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"),mapOpts);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position : latlng,
            map : map,
            title : "Somu's House, Bitches!"
        });

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content : "Somu's House, Bitches!"
        });

        $(marker).click(function() {
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }

    initMap();
});
```

The point of interest is the following lines

```
$(marker).click(function() {
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

The above code doesn't work (despite not generating any errors or warnings). However, according to the JavaScript API's sample code, the correct JS code is:

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

Why does the original code not work? How do I convert the above code to jQuery? What is the correct way of achieving the same in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`marker` is a google.maps.Marker instance. It's not a DOM element. So `$(marker).click()` doesn't work as you expect. (You are not clicking the "marker object")

Using marker's `addListener` method is the correct way to achieve it.

Comment: So the method to achieve this in jQuery is the exact same as the way to achieve this in plain JavaScript? Are there no changes that could be made using jQuery to make the code simpler?

Comment: I don't think you should do it with any jQuery methods, which involves finding the exact DOM element you click. I expect it to be very complicated and unnecessary.

Comment: Why use JQuery when you can do this with javascript ?

Comment: Using `plain JavaScript` is okay.  `addListener` is the official api for event listening. In another word, you are just using Google Map's api. Using the official api is PERFECT :)